# Couchbase buckets vs Ephemeral buckets

Tags: couchbase

Is Couchbase buckets store data in memory too?
I want to create live leaderboard system using Couchbase buckets and I run four different queries :

1- select existed rank 
2- update rank if existed (rank + 1)
3- insert rank and more data if not existed (rank = 1)

4- select from collection using limit 10 and order by rank desc.

I will be happy to listen to your suggestions to get best performance from Couchbase.
In this situation is there any difference using Normal Couchbase bucket or using Ephemeral buckets ?

I try to read Couchbase document [Couchbase Docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/buckets-memory-and-storage/buckets.html)
it's very good but I want to know more and use people experiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question "Does Couchbase buckets store data in memory too?" the answer is yes. Couchbase buckets are memory-first, mutations are queued up asynchronously to be written to disk.

Ephemeral buckets are memory-only. Meaning there is no queue to write mutations to the disk.

As for "best performance", that's really not a great question for Stack Overflow. You might consider the [Couchbase forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/) or the [Couchbase Discord](https://www.couchbase.com/blog/couchbase-on-discord/) to get some more opinions.

In general, Ephemeral will almost always be (*at least* slightly) faster than Couchbase buckets, [and for the most part they have the same capabilities](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/buckets-memory-and-storage/buckets.html#bucket-capabilities).

However, Ephemeral durability is only provided via memory on other nodes. If a whole cluster goes offline, and the data is not backed up or replicated elsewhere, that data might be lost forever (hence the name). So, I personally would only recommend Ephemeral if you want to optimize for pure performance and having memory-only durability is an acceptable trade-off.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I will ask it in Couchbase forums.